# How to figure when device was recently unlocked in Android?

Tags: android, orientation, unlock

I build an app which fires an activity every time the orientation changes, but I have an exception: I don't want the activity to fire within the next five seconds after phone was unlocked.

So after phone is unlocked I will disregard every phone orientation change for five seconds.
I thought I could get the *last-unlock-time* and  compare it with the current time?

Any suggestions of how to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register a broadcast receiver for [`ACTION_USER_PRESENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT), and start a handler in it to run your activity after a minimum of five seconds.

You'll have to regiester the receiver dynamically, as ACTION_USER_PRESENT is not called if you register from the manifest.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new YourReceiver();
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: *ACTION_USER_PRESENT is not called if you register from the manifest.*  why only this Action not work from manifest. im not agree on this point because i have already used it many time using manifest

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Even other actions like ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF need to be registered dynamically. I read the reason somewhere, but I've forgotten it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя: I think that is only valid for ACTION_SCREEN_ON/OFF. This article is interesting too: http://funwithdc.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/the-problem-with-androids-action_user_present-intent/

Comment: @André : i was already used these 3 Intent's by registering in manifest. if u have any official doc( or Romain Guy and CommonsWare blog links ) link about this then share it

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя: I would have bet that ACTION_SCREEN_ON doesn't work, if you add it to the manifest (see http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/ too). In my implementation I had definitely to register it dynamically in the code. Anyhow, this was not the question here :)

Comment: @André: i agree,if u have time then plz check [this example](https://sites.google.com/site/imrankhanandroid/Screenunlocktestnew.zip?attredirects=0&d=1) where all three intents working fine from manifest.